# Understanding a step in differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Whilst working on a question where we have $$\frac{du}{dt}=P(u)$$
There is a step in this questions which is $$2u^3= \frac{dP}{dt}P= \frac{d}{du}\frac{P^2}{2}$$

How do you go from the middle term to the final term? I just can't seem to understand how this is done. Thanks

Comment: What is $p$ here? It isn't same as $P$ right?

Comment: No they are the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question contains a typo, probably not originating with the poster. It should probably read as $$2u^3=u''=\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{dP}{du}u'=\frac{dP}{du}P=\frac{d}{du}\frac{P^2}2.$$ 
After integration, this gives $P(u)^2=u^4+C$.

Note that just multiplying with $2u'$ and integrating leads to the equivalent equation $u^4+C=u'^2$.

Answer (score 0):

From $\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{dP}{du}\frac{du}{dt}$, you can infer
$$\frac{dP}{dt}P=\frac{dP}{du}\frac{du}{dt}P=\frac{dP}{du}P^2$$
which should be, if I understand correctly, $\frac{d}{du}\frac{P^3}{3}$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand how you've got this

Comment: What don't you understand ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a classic problem which uses the same change of variable technique. The proof of Kepler's First Law, Planets orbit the sun in elliptical paths.

Starting with the Lagrangian, $$L_g= \frac{1}{2}mv_r^2 + \frac{1}{2}mr^2v_\theta^2+GMm/r$$, then solving the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations, you get that $$L=mr^2v_\theta^2$$, where L is the angular momentum, a constant of the motion, and $$m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=mrv_\theta^2-GMm/r^2$$. This can be simplified by swapping in the angular momentum: $$m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=Lv_\theta/r-GMm^2v_\theta/L$$.

Here is the technique used above, divide both sides by $$v_\theta$$. This will turn $$m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$$ into $$m\frac{d(\frac{dr}{dt})}{d\theta}$$, thus converting the differential equation with respect to time into a differential equation with respect to theta. This can be done again to convert $$\frac{dr}{dt}$$ into $$\frac{dr}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$. The time derivative of $\theta$ suggests swapping in the angular momentum, L.

This gives $$-L\frac{d^2\frac{1}{r}}{d\theta^2}=L/r-GMm^2/L$$, a differential equation representing an ellipse.